# How to forward data to jsp from Servlet multiple times using request dispatcher.

Tags: jsp, servlets

How to forward data to jsp from Servlet multiple times using request dispatcher.  I have tried with timer in servlet with request dispatcher to forward updated data from databases to jsp page to display result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work like that.  What you really want to do is either refresh the page periodically, which is simple but ugly, or use AJAX to update the results.  (I recommend using [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) if you don't already have a good JavaScript library.  They also have a good [AJAX tutorial](http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/).)  Either way, you have the browser request new data from the server with a new request.